# Table of time-varing calculation slower to the point of kernel blowing up

Tags: mathematical-optimization, code-review

There is a complicated function obtained by numerically solving a pde, let us call it $u(t,x,z)$.

For this $u$, I want to calculate the global maximum of $u^2$ at a fixed position of $z$, and plot such global maximum with respect to time so it is a $u-t$ plot. Given that I know the global maximum at time $t$ always occurs in between $x=3t$ and $x=3(t+1)$, I write the following code to create a table of points for plotting:

```
Points=Table[{t,First[FindMaximum[u[t,x,0]^2,{x,3t,3t+3}]]},{t,0,20,0.5}]
```

However while it usually takes around 30 seconds to calculate the maxima for a single time $t$, for example at $t=0.5$, when I write it in table form the kernel always crashes or I was sent message saying my dynamic environment is not responding.

Thus I am forced to manually note down every value of maxima by keep changing time $t$ myself. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Also for a function that is cos-like but with amplitude changing with phase, it seem that neither of the findingmaxima functions available in mathematica could reliably find the global maximum which definitely exists for my function.

Comment: Without a concrete example, we are just guessing. Try, `NSolve[{D[u[t, x, 0]^2, x] == 0, D[u[t, x, 0]^2, {x, 2}] < 0, 3 t <= x <= 3 t + 3, 0 <= t <= 20}, {x, t}, Reals]` or also include the derivatives with respect to `t`